# Top Level Site Missing in a site Collection Sp2013

Tags: 2013, site-collection

I ran into a weird issue in one of the Site collection on my farm. I have 4 different Web apps and 4  site collections underneath them. Today i tried to browse the top level site of a Site collection , it si throwing http 404 error, whereas on other sites in same server are working fine.

Then i went to manage web application in central admin and looked into the View all Site Collections Link where i found out top level site was missing "/" was missing on top. then i checked other sites underneath that same site collections, they are working as expected.

Then i went to another web application and checked next site collection top level site is there "/".

Is there a way we can receover that top level site of the effected Site Collection.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things need clarification:

1. You said in the web App "/" site missing but other sites are still their, what that mean...other sites mean "/sites/sitename" or subsite of the"/" site?
2. How many total site collection you can see in that web application.

Possible Solutions:

1. Make sure the content Database Attached to the web app( the one which having "/" site collection)
2. If it is deleted accidently then run this command and see if it is still in database...`[Get-SPDeletedSite][1] "/"`
3. If above command retrun the site collection then run the below command to restore it.[`Restore-SPDeletedSite][2] "/"`
4. Lastly if you have backup of your content database then restore it and recover the root site collection.

Ref:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316(v=office.15).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286319(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: For your first question : By other i mean https://xyz.com/sites/abc, https://xyz.com/sites/cde are still there and working. Its just "/" missing.

Comment: I have 15 total site collection under that web app

Comment: Ok....so clear either you "/" site collection deleted or the db which holding the site collection not attached....did you run the powershell?

Comment: I went to create site collection and created a top level site using managed path \sites\, issue got resolved. Thanks for your help.